# SELECT MAX subquery not allowed in WHERE clause when using WITH RECURSIVE in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, common-table-expression

[This LeetCode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-the-subtasks-that-did-not-execute/) with given schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
  Tasks (task_id int, subtasks_count int);

TRUNCATE TABLE Tasks;

INSERT INTO
  Tasks (task_id, subtasks_count)
VALUES
  ('1', '3'),
  ('2', '2'),
  ('3', '4');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
  Executed (task_id int, subtask_id int);

TRUNCATE TABLE Executed;

INSERT INTO
  Executed (task_id, subtask_id)
VALUES
  ('1', '2'),
  ('3', '1'),
  ('3', '2'),
  ('3', '3'),
  ('3', '4');
```

has the following as a possible solution when using MySQL version 8.0.23:

```
WITH RECURSIVE possible_tasks_subtasks AS (
  SELECT
    task_id, subtasks_count as max_subtask_count, 1 AS subtask_id
  FROM
    Tasks
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    task_id, max_subtask_count, subtask_id + 1
  FROM
    possible_tasks_subtasks
---> using SELECT MAX below is where the problem occurs with Postgres
  WHERE
    subtask_id < (SELECT MAX(max_subtask_count) FROM Tasks))
SELECT
  P.task_id, P.subtask_id
FROM
  possible_tasks_subtasks P
LEFT JOIN
  Executed E ON P.task_id = E.task_id AND P.subtask_id = E.subtask_id
WHERE
  E.task_id IS NULL OR E.subtask_id IS NULL;
```

When trying this out with Postgres 13.1, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE
```

This struck me as odd given that a seemingly similar solution (in terms of using `SELECT <aggregate-function>` in the `WHERE` clause) is offered in [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-agg.html) for aggregate functions:

> `SELECT city FROM weather WHERE temp_lo = (SELECT max(temp_lo) FROM weather);`

If I modify

```
WHERE
  subtask_id < (SELECT MAX(max_subtask_count) FROM Tasks)
```

in the solution code block above to be

```
WHERE
  subtask_id < (SELECT max_subtask_count FROM Tasks ORDER BY max_subtask_count DESC LIMIT 1)
```

then Postgres does not throw an error. As a sanity check, I tried

```
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE task_id < (SELECT MAX(subtasks_count) FROM Tasks);
```

just to make sure I could use `SELECT MAX` in a subquery for a `WHERE` clause as the docs suggested, and *this* worked as expected.

The only determination I can make thus far is that this somehow has to do with how Postgres processes things when using `WITH RECURSIVE`. But [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) on `WITH` queries does not say anything about using aggregates in subqueries for `WHERE` clauses.

What am I missing here? Why does this work in MySQL but not Postgres? But more importantly, why does the solution offered in the docs not seem to work when using `WITH RECURSIVE` (from my reading and experimenting anyway)?

**EDIT:** For additional context in terms of the LeetCode problem and what it is asking you to accomplish with your query:

**Table:** `Tasks`

```
+----------------+---------+
| Column Name    | Type    |
+----------------+---------+
| task_id        | int     |
| subtasks_count | int     |
+----------------+---------+
```

- `task_id` is the primary key for this table.
- Each row in this table indicates that `task_id` was divided into `subtasks_count` subtasks labelled from `1` to `subtasks_count`.
- It is guaranteed that `2 <= subtasks_count <= 20`.

**Table:** `Executed`

```
+---------------+---------+
| Column Name   | Type    |
+---------------+---------+
| task_id       | int     |
| subtask_id    | int     |
+---------------+---------+
```

- `(task_id, subtask_id)` is the primary key for this table.
- Each row in this table indicates that for the task `task_id`, the subtask with ID `subtask_id` was executed successfully.
- It is **guaranteed** that `subtask_id <= subtasks_count` for each `task_id`.

Write an SQL query to report the IDs of the missing subtasks for each `task_id`. Return the result table in **any order**. The query result format is in the following example:

```
Tasks table:
+---------+----------------+
| task_id | subtasks_count |
+---------+----------------+
| 1       | 3              |
| 2       | 2              |
| 3       | 4              |
+---------+----------------+

Executed table:
+---------+------------+
| task_id | subtask_id |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | 2          |
| 3       | 1          |
| 3       | 2          |
| 3       | 3          |
| 3       | 4          |
+---------+------------+

Result table:
+---------+------------+
| task_id | subtask_id |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | 1          |
| 1       | 3          |
| 2       | 1          |
| 2       | 2          |
+---------+------------+
```

Comment: I don't want to create an account for LeetCode to look at further info. What should that query do?

Comment: Does LeetCode really teach you to specify integer values as strings?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's just the provided schema by the problem creator (whoever that may be). I don't think LeetCode really *teaches* you anything so much as provides different problems (of varying quality no doubt) against which to test your knowledge.

Comment: You need to read the documentation a little more carefully. What the documentation you referenced for aggregate functions actually says "SELECT city FROM weather WHERE temp_lo = max(temp_lo);     *WRONG*". and immediately afterwards goes on the say 
"but this **will not work** since the aggregate max cannot be used in the WHERE clause." (emphasis mine)

Comment: @Belayer [It looks like](https://i.imgur.com/oghy7SO.png) you are the one who needs to read the documentation a little more carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response by [Tom Lane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Lane_(computer_scientist)):

[image]

Reproduced for ease of reading:

> As the query is written, the aggregate is over a field of `possible_tasks_subtasks`, making it illegal in `WHERE`, just as the error says. (From the point of view of the `SELECT FROM Tasks` subquery, it's a constant outer reference, not an aggregate of that subquery. This is per SQL spec.)

With this guidance, a successful restated query in PostgreSQL is as follows:

```
WITH RECURSIVE possible_tasks_subtasks AS (
  SELECT
    task_id, subtasks_count, 1 AS subtask_id
  FROM
    Tasks
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    task_id, subtasks_count, subtask_id + 1
  FROM
    possible_tasks_subtasks
  WHERE
    subtask_id < (SELECT MAX(subtasks_count) FROM Tasks))
SELECT
  P.task_id, P.subtask_id
FROM
  possible_tasks_subtasks P
LEFT JOIN
  Executed E ON P.task_id = E.task_id AND P.subtask_id = E.subtask_id
WHERE
  E.task_id IS NULL AND P.subtasks_count >= P.subtask_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the MAX() to find the subtask count from the tasks table. Just carry that information over from the initial query in the recursive part.

I would also use a NOT EXISTS condition to get this result:

```
with recursive all_subtasks as (
  select task_id, 1 as subtask_id, subtasks_count 
  from tasks
  union all
  select t.task_id, p.subtask_id + 1, p.subtasks_count
  from tasks t
    join all_subtasks p on p.task_id = t.task_id
  where p.subtask_id  < p.subtasks_count
)
select st.task_id, st.subtask_id
from all_subtasks st
where not exists (select *
                  from executed e
                  where e.task_id = st.task_id
                    and e.subtask_id = st.subtask_id)
order by t.task_id, t.subtask_id;
```

In Postgres this can be written a bit simpler using `generate_series()`

```
select t.task_id, st.subtask_id
from tasks t
  cross join generate_series(1, t.subtasks_count) as st(subtask_id)
where not exists (select * 
                  from executed e
                  where e.task_id = t.task_id
                    and e.subtask_id = st.subtask_id)
order by t.task_id;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3ddd45c893a5d330fcbab776b9e9925f)

---

As to "why isn't an aggregate allowed in the recursive part" - the answer is quite simple: nobody of the Postgres development team though it was important enough to implement it.

Comment: See Tom Lane's explanation below--it looks like the query should probably not work in MySQL per SQL spec but does anyway. This is not because the Postgres development team did not think this important enough to implement. Thank you for the alternative approaches--I have no doubt my query could be improved in myriad ways, but I am glad to know I can use what I was trying to use--I was simply using it incorrectly.